# Can any 2D tessellation be uniquely determined by for each n the number of cycles of length n containing any given vertex?

Tags: graph-theory, tessellations

Basically what it says in the title. The title was actually intended to be:

"Can any 2D tessellation be uniquely determined by a partition of its vertices into types and for each type a sequence where the nth value is the number of cycles of length n containing any given vertex of that type?"

but that was too long. When I say cycle here I mean it in the graph theory sense - pretend the tessellation is just a graph. I have a hunch that this is the case, but I don't know.

Example: a square tiling of the plane has one type of vertex, characterized by being in no odd-length cycles, exactly four cycles of length 2 (edges), four cycles of length 4 (the square faces adjacent to the vertex), etc.

I feel like this, for each n, may be enough information to uniquely identify it across all possible tessellations of the plane or perhaps of any other surface - but I don't know that, and I wouldn't be able to guess how to prove it.

Comment: There are some tesselations that are topologically identical (and therefore have the same cycle count), though you might not notice that straight away. For example the non-edge-to-edge tilings [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_tilings_by_convex_regular_polygons#Tilings_that_are_not_edge-to-edge). Even though they are topologically identical, if you take the geometric symmetries into account their vertex types are different. It is unclear to me if that is how you would classify vertex types.

Comment: I suddenly realize I was actually thinking topologically anyway! In my head, for instance, a square tiling "feels" exactly the same as a tiling by, say, parallelograms, and the tilings on that page that are topologically equivalent also "feel" the same to me, so I suppose I must actually be talking about the topological properties of tilings rather than their geometric properties.